# ReactJs - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

My 2 files:

**APP:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NICE, SUPER_NICE } from './colors';
import Counter from './counter';

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Counter increment={ 1 } color={ NICE } />
        <Counter increment={ 5 } color={ SUPER_NICE } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Counter:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { counter: 0 };
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1 style={ { color: this.props.color } }>
        Counter ( { this.props.increment } ): { this.state.counter }
      </h1>
    );
  }
}

Counter.defaultProps = {
  increment: 0,
  color: null
};

Counter.propTypes = {
  increment: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  color: React.propTypes.string.isRequired
};


module.exports = Counter;
```

---

**I am using:**

```
"react": "^0.14.0-rc1",
"eslint": "^1.3.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^0.1.0",
"eslint-loader": "^1.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^3.0.0"
```

I need the declare the propTypes to satisfy eslint, but I am receiving a run-error:

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined".**

Does anyone see my error?

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the counter propTypes, the "color" React.PropTypes should be capitalized.

```
Counter.propTypes = {
  increment: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  color: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Comment: I feel like a schmuck. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar problem with `React.PropTypes`, as I am using React-16 I found out that `React.PropTypes` is not supported. 
So you need to install `"prop-types": "^15.6.0"` using

```
npm install prop-types --save
```

and then import it as shown below

```
import PropType from 'prop-types'
```

I made a mistake while importing, instead of `prop-types` I imported `prop-type` and that was the issue for me.

Posting as an answer so others can get idea about newer package and how to install etc.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It fix the problem for me! There is just a type which should be fixed! import PropType from 'prop-types' --> import PropTypes from 'prop-types'. Also I use -g parameter for npm install -->  npm install -g prop-types --save